# Where is IFileOperation implemented (and how can I verify this)?

Tags: c++, winapi, com, windows-7

I am trying to find out where `IFileOperation` is implemented in Windows 7.
As far as I understand from [the MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775771.aspx) it is in shell32.dll.

So, I checked all the COM objects in shell32.dll using a DLL export viewer (from NirSoft) and IFileOperation is not one of them.

I searched the registry for the `CLSID_FileOperation` {3ad05575-8857-4850-9277-11b85bdb8e09} and I found (as far as I understand) that it is in shell32.dll.

But how can that be if I couldn't find that COM export using DLL export?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A DLL doesn't need to export anything special to implement that interface. The registry tells the OS what DLL implements the interface. When a program calls `CoCreateInstance`, the OS can look up the given CLSID in the registry. The OS then loads the associated DLL and calls its `DllGetClassObject` function to get an `IClassFactory` object. The OS then uses that interface to get something that implements the requested interface.

Comment: I'm [trying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62065891/how-to-use-ifileoperation-from-ctypes) to use `IFileOperation` from `ctypes` in Python to get a Windows copy dialog. Is the implication of the DLL not being exported that I can't use it from Python?

Comment: @Jay - You'll need to load it as a COM object

Comment: Could you elaborate in the question? Not sure how it's done..

Comment: No DLL gets exported. _Functions_ are exported _from_ DLLs. You _could_ do as the OS does and load the DLL, get DllGetClassObject, call it to get an IClassFactory, and then use that to get the interface you really want. Seems like that's already done by the pythoncom module, though, so I don't know why you wouldn't just use that instead.

Comment: @RobKennedy  I don't want to carry the dependency, which seems to have its own dependencies. I would like to know the "vanilla" way to do it from Python if that's possible