# IDropTarget::Drop method Hooking

Tags: c++, com, api-hook

I am trying to hook IDropTarget::Drop COM method but i am not, before this i was hooking the IFileOperation::RenameItems  Method it is working fine and for RenameItems hooking i used the following code ..

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include "MinHook.h"
#include <Winternl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <shlwapi.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <psapi.h>
#include <strsafe.h>
#include <Shobjidl.h>
#include <Shellapi.h>   
#include <Shlguid.h>

#if defined _M_X64
#pragma comment(lib, "libMinHook.x64.lib")
bool __is32bitMachine = false ;
#elif defined _M_IX86
#pragma comment(lib, "libMinHook.x86.lib")
bool __is32bitMachine = true;
#endif

PVOID GetInterfaceMethod(PVOID intf, DWORD methodIndex)
{
if (__is32bitMachine)
    return *(PVOID*)(*(DWORD_PTR*)intf + methodIndex * 4);
else
    return *(PVOID*)(*(DWORD_PTR*)intf + methodIndex * 8);
}

typedef HRESULT (STDMETHODCALLTYPE *RenameItemsNext)(IFileOperation *pThis, IUnknown *pUnkItems, LPCWSTR pszNewName);
 RenameItemsNext Real_RenameItems = NULL;
 RenameItemsNext Actual_RenameItems ;

HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE RenameItemsCallback(IFileOperation *pThis, IUnknown *pUnkItems, LPCWSTR pszNewName)
{
IID IID_ShellItemArray; 
IID IID_DataObject; 
CLSIDFromString(L"{b63ea76d-1f85-456f-a19c-48159efa858b}", &IID_ShellItemArray);
CLSIDFromString(L"{0000010E-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}", &IID_DataObject); 

void *shellItemArray;
void *dataObject;
LPWSTR dstFN;

if (pUnkItems->QueryInterface(IID_ShellItemArray, &shellItemArray) == S_OK)
{
    DWORD numItems = 0;
    IShellItem *shell;
    IShellItemArray *pItems = (IShellItemArray *) pUnkItems;
    pItems->GetCount(&numItems);
    for (int i = 0; i < numItems; i++)
    {
        pItems->GetItemAt(i, &shell);
        shell->GetDisplayName(SIGDN_FILESYSPATH, &dstFN);
        MessageBoxW(NULL, dstFN, L"Renamed From", MB_OK);
    }
    MessageBoxW(NULL, pszNewName, L"Renamed To", MB_OK);
}

if (pUnkItems->QueryInterface(IID_DataObject, &dataObject) == S_OK)
{
    Real_SHCreateShell = (SHCreateShellNext)GetProcAddress(LoadLibraryA("shell32.dll"), "SHCreateShellItemArrayFromDataObject");
    if (Real_SHCreateShell != NULL)
    {
        if (Real_SHCreateShell((IDataObject*)dataObject, IID_ShellItemArray, &shellItemArray) == S_OK)
        {
            DWORD numItems = 0;
            IShellItem *shell;
            IShellItemArray *pItems = (IShellItemArray *)shellItemArray;
            pItems->GetCount(&numItems);
            if (pItems->GetCount(&numItems) == S_OK)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < numItems; i++)
                {
                    if (pItems->GetItemAt(i, &shell) == S_OK)
                    {
                        shell->GetDisplayName(SIGDN_FILESYSPATH, &dstFN);
                        MessageBoxW(NULL, dstFN, L"Renamed From", MB_OK);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    MessageBoxW(NULL, dstFN, L"Renamed To", MB_OK);
}
return Real_RenameItems(pThis, pUnkItems, pszNewName);
}

typedef HRESULT (WINAPI *COCREATEINSTANCE)(REFCLSID, LPUNKNOWN, DWORD, REFIID, LPVOID*);
COCREATEINSTANCE Real_CoCreateInstance = NULL;  

HRESULT WINAPI CoCreateInstanceCallback(REFCLSID rclsid, LPUNKNOWN pUnkOuter, DWORD dwClsContext, REFIID riid, LPVOID *ppv)
{
const char *IFileOperation_GUID = "{3AD05575-8857-4850-9277-11B85BDB8E09}";
char GUIDString[64];

HRESULT HR = Real_CoCreateInstance(rclsid, pUnkOuter, dwClsContext, riid, ppv);

sprintf_s(GUIDString, 64, "{%08X-%04X-%04X-%02X%02X-%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X}\0",
    rclsid.Data1, rclsid.Data2, rclsid.Data3,
    rclsid.Data4[0], rclsid.Data4[1],
    rclsid.Data4[2], rclsid.Data4[3],
    rclsid.Data4[4], rclsid.Data4[5],
    rclsid.Data4[6], rclsid.Data4[7]);

if (strcmp(GUIDString, IFileOperation_GUID) == 0)
{       
    if(Real_RenameItems == NULL)
    {
        Actual_RenameItems = (RenameItemsNext) GetInterfaceMethod(*ppv, 13);

        if (MH_CreateHook(Actual_RenameItems, &RenameItemsCallback, reinterpret_cast<void**>(&Real_RenameItems)) != MH_OK)
        {
            MessageBoxW(NULL, L"Failed CreateHook Real_RenameItems", L"Info!", MB_ICONWARNING|MB_OK);
        }
        if (MH_EnableHook(Actual_RenameItems) != MH_OK)
        {
            MessageBoxW(NULL, L"Failed EnableHook Real_RenameItems", L"Info!", MB_ICONWARNING|MB_OK);
        }
    }
}
return HR;
}

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HMODULE hModule, DWORD  ul_reason_for_call, LPVOID lpReserved)
{
switch (ul_reason_for_call)
{
case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
    if (MH_Initialize() != MH_OK)
    {
        MessageBoxW(NULL, L"Failed Initialize", L"Info!", MB_ICONWARNING|MB_OK);    
    }
    if (MH_CreateHook(&CoCreateInstance, &CoCreateInstanceCallback, reinterpret_cast<void**>(&Real_CoCreateInstance)) != MH_OK)
    {
        MessageBoxW(NULL, L"Failed MH_CreateHook CoCreateInstance", L"Info!", MB_ICONWARNING|MB_OK);
    }
    if (MH_EnableHook(&CoCreateInstance) != MH_OK)
    {
        MessageBoxW(NULL, L"Failed MH_EnableHook CoCreateInstance", L"Info!", MB_ICONWARNING|MB_OK);
    }
    break;

case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
    if (MH_Uninitialize() != MH_OK)
    {               
    }
    if (MH_DisableHook(Actual_RenameItems) != MH_OK)
    {
    }
    if (MH_DisableHook(&CoCreateInstance) != MH_OK)
    {
    }
    break;
}
return TRUE;
 }
```

The above code is working fine for IOFileOperation::RenameItems and i am trying to implement the same code for IDropTarget::Drop Method but what is happening is the CoCreateInstance Function itself is not calling for Drop operation , so can any help me how to implement this IDropTarget::Drop Hooking .......

Comment: Not every COM interface is part of a coclass that gets created with CoCreateInstance().  IDropTarget is implemented by a window that supports dropping stuff on it.  It will never call CoCreateInstance(), it already has an instance.

Comment: ok ... would you please suggest me the way how can we implement that ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually IDropTarget is implemented inside client application and registered with RegisterDropTarget call.
Try to hook RegisterDropTarget function, may be it helps

**Update**: actually the function name is RegisterDragDrop

Comment: i didn't find the RegisterDropTarget function so can you please tell which function that exactly i should try ....

Comment: sorry it is named RegisterDragDrop [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms678405(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: its okay ... and I tried with RegisterDragDrop function but it didn't help because it is not calling during Drag and Drop Operation .. . so any other way please help ..

Comment: RegisterDragDrop called by client application for a window only once (for instance after creation), after this the window can accept dropping object. During drag and drop, system detects if window under cursor has a drop target object, then it calls different IDropTarget interface methods. The actual drag and drop is happening in DoDragDrop method, please check this link [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms678486(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: thank you so much for answer, i tried by hooking DoDragDrop Method it works fine, but my aim was to do this by using COM methods, we can't achieve this by using COM methods ...?

Comment: Finally it is working fine as my wish ..thank you so much Serik  for your help ...

Comment: I understand from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5010620/where-is-ifileoperation-implemented-and-how-can-i-verify-this) that DLL functions don't have to be "exported". Are such functions not available from `ctypes` as well? I'm [trying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62065891/how-to-use-ifileoperation-from-ctypes) to use `IFileOperation` to get a windows copy dialog, but can't find it in `shell32`